# Drupal 7 block.tpl.php does not exist

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I am new in Drupal and try to create my own Drupal theme. I have copied the Garland theme from `theme/garland` and pasted it to `sites/all/themes/(renamed mytheme)`. But when I search on how to integrate templates in Drupal, there I got that I need four mandatory files: `comment.tpl.php, page.tpl.php, node.tpl.php and block.tpl.php` but in that theme there is no file name called `block.tpl.php`, inspite I have a `template.php`.

Please guide me on this, do I need to create `block.tpl.php` by myself?? If I create it what would be its content and how do I use that, also what is the use of `template.php` in my site.

I am new in this CMS (Drupal) so any response would be appreciable and helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `block.tpl.php` by copying it form `modules/block` to your theme's folder (remember to clear the cache!). template.php should contain custom overrides to the theme functions, as well as implementations of process/preprocess hooks. You can find an in-depth discussion about how Drupal's theme system work by following [this link](https://drupal.org/node/173880) and in general by searching drupal.org website.

Comment: thanks @pamatt , but also i need to customize the custom drupal login module , could you help me on that.

Comment: as I have created a block.tpl.php all the other default functionality are not working lke /node/1 this is not showing any data though i have a static page created in the admin and whenever i rename/remove the block.tpl.php it works, I m totally puzzled.